# Is there a way to identify colours in a mesh

Tags: image, text-object

So, I've imported an image as a plane. It's a simple logo, just black with a company's name in white font.

Is there a way I can identify the white font as a separate material, so as to remove the font and make a cut-out plaque?

Comment: To me this sounds like something that's easier to accomplish in a photo editing program to create a picture of the logo on a transparent background, then using that  on your model as an image texture to influence your material.

Comment: yeah I guess you're right hehe :) thanks bro!

Answer (score 6):

Sure thing.
Just use the black and white image as a *mask* for transparency.

Connect your material nodes like this.
And use the *Transparent BSDF node*.
[image]

*If you're using Evee, don't forget to enable Alpha Blend* 
[image]

You can also combine different colors the same way.
*All of these planes were created using the same bw image.* 
[image]